# Pandas match multi-column patterns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe consisting of boolean values. I'd like to match certain multi-column patterns in the dataframe. The pattern would look like:

```
    bar     foo
0   False   True
1   True    False
```

And the expected output would look like:

```
      foo    bar pattern
0    True  False   False
1    True  False   False
2    True  False    True
3   False   True   False
4   False   True   False
5   False   True   False
6   False  False   False
7   False  False   False
8   False  False   False
9   False   True   False
10  False   True   False
11  False   True   False
12  False   True   False
13  False   True   False
14  False   True   False
15  False   True   False
16   True  False   False
17   True  False   False
18   True  False    True
19  False   True   False
20  False   True   False
21  False   True   False
22   True  False    True
23  False   True   False
24  False   True   False
25  False   True   False
```

I came up with my own implementation, but I guess there should be a better one.

```
def matcher(df, pattern):
    def aggregator(pattern):
        """Returns a dict of columnswith their aggregator function
        which is the partially applied inner in this case"""
        def inner(col, window):
            return (window == pattern[col]).all()
        return {col: partial(inner, col) for col in pattern.columns}

    aggregated = (df
                  # Feed the chunks to aggregator in `len(pattern)` sized windows
                  .rolling(len(pattern))
                  .aggregate(aggregator(pattern))
                  # I'd like it to return True at the beginning of the match
                  .shift(-len(pattern) + 1)
                  # rows consisting of nan return true to `.all()`
                  .fillna(False))
    ret = [row.all() for _, row in aggregated.iterrows()]
    return pd.Series(ret)
```

My biggest concern is handling nan values, and the lack of wildcard support (in order to support not necessarily box-shaped patterns).

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean with wildcard support?

Comment: My idea is to match any value on a given position. Like `*` in regex

Answer (score 1):

If `pd.concat()` is not too expensive to you, below code will work quite well with efficiency because there is no loop and no nested function.

```
print(df)  # Original data without 'pattern' column.

df_wide = pd.concat([df, df.shift(-1)], axis=1)
df_wide.columns = ['foo0', 'bar0', 'foo-1', 'bar-1']

pat = ((df_wide['foo0'] == True) & (df_wide['bar-1'] == True)) & \
      ((df_wide['bar0'] == False) & (df_wide['foo-1'] == False)) 

df['pattern'] = False
df.loc[df_wide[pat].index, 'pattern'] = True

print(df)  # Result data with 'pattern' column.

# Original data without 'pattern' column.
      foo    bar
0    True  False
1    True  False
2    True  False
3   False   True
4   False   True
5   False   True
...

# Result data with 'pattern' column.
      foo    bar  pattern
0    True  False    False
1    True  False    False
2    True  False     True
3   False   True    False
4   False   True    False
5   False   True    False
6   False  False    False
7   False  False    False
8   False  False    False
9   False   True    False
10  False   True    False
11  False   True    False
12  False   True    False
13  False   True    False
14  False   True    False
15  False   True    False
16   True  False    False
17   True  False    False
18   True  False     True
19  False   True    False
20  False   True    False
21  False   True    False
22   True  False     True
23  False   True    False
24  False   True    False
25  False   True    False
```

Comment: I like this solution, but my problem is, it doesn't provide the interface I'm looking for (ok, I could transform it to work with an arbitrary pattern, but the longer the pattern the more memory it requires).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose df1 is your patten df and df2 is your value df, you can use apply to check the pattern. For every row, we get the current row and the next row and then compare the 2*2 array with df1 element else and check if all elements are the same.

```
df2.apply(lambda x: (df2[['foo','bar']].iloc[x.name:x.name+2].values\
                     ==df1[['foo','bar']].values).all(),axis=1)
Out[213]: 
0     False
1     False
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
15    False
16    False
17    False
18     True
19    False
20    False
21    False
22     True
23    False
24    False
25    False
dtype: bool
```